# Does anyone know why I have two "Summary" tabs on each contact when I use a custom template?

Tags: contacts, core

I use a custom template for the "Summary" tab. In recent versions of CiviCRM, this has created two identical "Summary" tabs at the top of each contact. Both of these tabs work correctly and bring up identical fields from the custom template - see image.

Has anyone else had this happen with a custom template? It looks like a bug to raise.

[image: Duplicate summary tabs]

I am using Drupal with CiviCRM 4.7.10

Comment: Check after removing the template cache files.

Comment: No change after removing the template cache files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now checked for any changes to the template since v4.7.0 and there are changes. I've now incorporated these into my custom template and this has fixed the problem. Please ignore the question!